# Get input textbox value into a PHP variable in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get a input textbox value in a PHP variable and then update a table based on this variable value in my custom WordPress page. I have written following code.

It is working but not updating the text input value. What is wrong with my code?

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <td>
    <table> <tr><td> </td><input type="text" name="offeramt" style="height:15px"/> <td>
 <input type="hidden" name="pid" value= "<?php echo $retrieved_data->id; ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="textamount" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['offeramt']);?>">
 <input type="submit" name="update" value="update"  /></td> </table></td>
</form>

<?php 


 if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

        $sellamt=$_POST['textamount'];

        if (empty($sellamt)){
         echo "pls input a value in text box";
        }

        else{

        $myid = $_POST['pid'];

        ?> <?php
             $wpdb->update('wp_share', array('status'=>'onsell','offervalue'=>$sellamt),array('id'=>$myid));

        }}


}?>
```

Comment: what is it not updating? the database or the html form input value?

Comment: html form input value is not updating, database is updating status=onsell but not updating the offervalue=sellamt. whatever i input in textbox it always remains zero

Comment: try to go to the source of the page and check whether the value is being put in the hidden input or not? by d way from where are you getting the offeramt? the POST one?

Comment: offeramt is from the textbox input.

Answer (score 0):

I was updating the text input value to a hidden field ["textamount"]then trying to get that hidden field  ["textamount"] value to $sellamt. However I have removed the hidden field and took the value directly from textbox like this

```
$sellamt=$_POST['offeramt'];
```

where ['offeramt'] is the textbox itself
and its working.Thanks